# using json_normalize to flatten data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use pandas to flatten this json file. I have pasted an example below. I want my final output to have the following columns.

['Procedure Code', 'Procedure Name', 'Gross Charge', 'Insurance Payer Name', 'Insurance Rate']

Any suggestions? Using the function `pd.json_normalize(data)` but it isnt flattening the data frame correctly because there is no key for the nest "InsuranceRates".

```
[
   {
    "ProcedureCode": "70023090",
    "ProcedureName": "HVY MTAL PRO II BLOOD LC706200",
    "Charge": 27.46,
    "AltCodes": {
     "CPT": "82300",
     "MEDI-CAL": "82300"
    },
    "InsuranceRates": {
     "ACCESS MEDICAL GROUP COMMERCIAL": 35.46,
     "ACCESS MEDICAL GROUP MEDICARE": 23.64,
     "AETNA COMMERCIAL": 62.56,
     "AETNA MEDICARE": 23.64,
     "AETNA WORKERS COMP": 22.93,
     "ALIGNMENT FKA CITIZENS CHOICE HP MEDICARE": 23.64,
     "ANTHEM BLUE CROSS COMMERCIAL": 106.01,
     "ANTHEM BLUE CROSS COMMERCIAL (INS. EXCHANGE)": 89.23,
     "ANTHEM BLUE CROSS MEDI-CAL": 17.28,
     "ANTHEM BLUE CROSS MEDICARE": 23.64,
     "ANTHEM BLUE CROSS WORKERS COMP": 22.93,
     "AXMINSTER MEDICAL GROUP MEDICARE": 23.64,
     "BLUE SHIELD CA - VA": 23.64,
     "BLUE SHIELD PROMISE FKA CARE 1ST HP MEDI-CAL": 16.46,
     "BLUE SHIELD PROMISE FKA CARE 1ST HP MEDI-CARE": 23.64,
     "CENTINELA VALLEY IPA COMMERCIAL": 37.11,
     "CENTINELA VALLEY IPA COMMERCIAL (INS. EXCHANGE)": 37.11,
     "CENTINELA VALLEY IPA MEDICAL": 23.64,
     "CENTINELA VALLEY IPA MEDICARE": 23.64,
     "DISCOUNTED CASH PRICE": 23.64,
     "EMPLOYER DIRECT HEALTHCARE (SURGERY PLUS) COMMERCIAL": 30.73,
     "HEALTH NET FEDERAL SERVICES (TRICARE) TRICARE": 23.64,
     "HEALTH NET OF CA CAL MEDICONNECT": 23.64,
     "HEALTH NET OF CA COMMERCIAL (ENHANCED PPO)": 29.55,
     "HEALTH NET OF CA COMMERCIAL (INS. EXCHANGE)": 30.73,
     "HEALTH NET OF CA MEDI-CAL": 16.46,
     "HEALTH NET OF CA MEDICARE": 23.64,
     "HEALTHNET OF CA COMMERCIAL": 13.73,
     "IMPERIAL HEALTH PLAN OF CA, INC. MEDICARE": 25.06,
     "KINDRED HOSPITAL - LA MEDI-CAL": 23.64,
     "KINDRED HOSPITAL - LA MEDICARE": 23.64,
     "LA CARE HEALTH PLAN COVEREDCA AND COVERED DIRECT": 23.64,
     "LA CARE HEALTH PLAN DUALS": 23.64,
     "LA CARE HEALTH PLAN MEDI-CAL": 16.46,
     "MOLINA HEALTHCARE OF CALIFORNIA EXCHANGE": 23.64,
     "MOLINA HEALTHCARE OF CALIFORNIA MEDI-CAL": 16.46,
     "MOLINA HEALTHCARE OF CALIFORNIA MEDICARE & MA-SNP": 23.64,
     "NAPHCARE (RESIDENTIAL TREATMENT CENTER) PRISON": 36.64,
     "OPTUM HEALTH PLAN OF CALIFORNIA (FKA DAVITA EALTH PLAN - HEALTHCARE PARTNERS) COMMERCIAL (HMO,EPO, POS)": 15.1,
     "OPTUM HEALTH PLAN OF CALIFORNIA (FKA DAVITA HEALTH PLAN - HEALTHCARE PARTNERS) MEDI-CAL": 18.1,
     "OPTUM HEALTH PLAN OF CALIFORNIA (FKA DAVITA HEALTH PLAN - HEALTHCARE PARTNERS) MEDICARE": 23.64,
     "PREMIER PHYSICIANS NETWORK COMMERCIAL & INS. EXCHANGE": 37.11,
     "PREMIER PHYSICIANS NETWORK MEDI-CAL": 23.64,
     "PREMIER PHYSICIANS NETWORK MEDICARE CAL MEDICONNECT, MA & DUALS": 23.64
    },
    "De-Identified Minimum": 13.73,
    "De-Identified Maximum": 106.01
   },
   {
    "ProcedureCode": "142330",
    "ProcedureName": "ENDOVAS AAA REPR W/LONG TUBE",
    "Charge": 0.01,
    "AltCodes": {
     "CPT": "34703",
     "MEDI-CAL": "34703"
    },
    "InsuranceRates": {
     "ANTHEM BLUE CROSS COMMERCIAL": 233.0,
     "ANTHEM BLUE CROSS COMMERCIAL (INS. EXCHANGE)": 196.0,
     "CENTINELA VALLEY IPA COMMERCIAL": 90.0,
     "CENTINELA VALLEY IPA COMMERCIAL (INS. EXCHANGE)": 90.0,
     "CENTINELA VALLEY IPA MEDICAL": 90.0,
     "CENTINELA VALLEY IPA MEDICARE": 90.0,
     "HEALTH NET FEDERAL SERVICES (TRICARE) TRICARE": 0.01,
     "HEALTHNET OF CA COMMERCIAL": 0.01,
     "OPTUM HEALTH PLAN OF CALIFORNIA (FKA DAVITA EALTH PLAN - HEALTHCARE PARTNERS) COMMERCIAL (HMO,EPO, POS)": 170.0
    },
    "De-Identified Minimum": 0.01,
    "De-Identified Maximum": 233.0
   },
   {
    "ProcedureCode": "20000014",
    "ProcedureName": "MED/SURG DAILY",
    "Charge": 3100.0,
    "InsuranceRates": {
     "AETNA COMMERCIAL": 6042.0,
     "CENTINELA VALLEY IPA MEDICAL": 1550.0,
     "HEALTH NET OF CA MEDI-CAL": 465.0,
     "OPTUM HEALTH PLAN OF CALIFORNIA (FKA DAVITA EALTH PLAN - HEALTHCARE PARTNERS) COMMERCIAL (HMO,EPO, POS)": 2500.0,
     "PREMIER PHYSICIANS NETWORK MEDI-CAL": 1550.0
    },
    "De-Identified Minimum": 465.0,
    "De-Identified Maximum": 6042.0
   },
   {
    "ProcedureCode": "20000220",
    "ProcedureName": "MICU PRIVATE",
    "Charge": 7400.0,
    "AltCodes": {
     "MEDICARE": "G0378"
    },
    "InsuranceRates": {
     "AETNA COMMERCIAL": 6728.0,
     "CENTINELA VALLEY IPA MEDICAL": 3700.0,
     "HEALTH NET OF CA MEDI-CAL": 1110.0,
     "OPTUM HEALTH PLAN OF CALIFORNIA (FKA DAVITA EALTH PLAN - HEALTHCARE PARTNERS) COMMERCIAL (HMO,EPO, POS)": 3400.0,
     "PREMIER PHYSICIANS NETWORK MEDI-CAL": 3700.0
    },
    "De-Identified Minimum": 1110.0,
    "De-Identified Maximum": 6728.0
   },
   {
    "ProcedureCode": "20000360",
    "ProcedureName": "MICU DAILY RM C LEVEL 3",
    "Charge": 7900.0,
    "InsuranceRates": {
     "AETNA COMMERCIAL": 6728.0,
     "CENTINELA VALLEY IPA MEDICAL": 3950.0,
     "HEALTH NET OF CA MEDI-CAL": 1185.0,
     "OPTUM HEALTH PLAN OF CALIFORNIA (FKA DAVITA EALTH PLAN - HEALTHCARE PARTNERS) COMMERCIAL (HMO,EPO, POS)": 3400.0,
     "PREMIER PHYSICIANS NETWORK MEDI-CAL": 3950.0
    },
    "De-Identified Minimum": 1185.0,
    "De-Identified Maximum": 6728.0
   }
]
```

Comment: There is no "Insurance Payer Name" in your data.  And although we always want sample data, you have probably violated several non-disclosure agreements by publishing that data.

Comment: The data is public. Insurance payor name are the alt-codes.

Comment: So, in the first case, do you want two lines, one for CPT, one for MEDI-CAL?  Since those are not listed in the "InsuranceRates" list, how will you know what rate to use?

Comment: I can create another thread for that issue because that is a problem of its own. Ideally, I will want one value that combines each value in the list. For example, for the first listing the value should be 'CPT, Medi-Cal' as our single value. We can skip that for now.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share the expected output.

Comment: `['Procedure Code', 'Procedure Name', 'Gross Charge', 'Insurance Payer Name', 'Insurance Rate']`

These would be the columns

Comment: I mean what values in what format you want in those columns.  Show it in a table so that we can exactly know a value comes from which part in JSON.

Comment: `ProcedureCode ProcedureName GrossCharge Insurance Payer Name Insurance Rate
70023090 HVY MTAL PRO II BLOOD LC706200 27.46 ACCESS MEDICAL GROUP COMMERCIAL 35.46
70023090 HVY MTAL PRO II BLOOD LC706201 27.46 ACCESS MEDICAL GROUP MEDICARE 23.64
70023090 HVY MTAL PRO II BLOOD LC706202 27.46 AETNA COMMERCIAL 62.56
70023090 HVY MTAL PRO II BLOOD LC706203 27.46 AETNA MEDICARE 23.64`


this should be 5 columns with 4 rows

Comment: Please edit your question to add these details, so they can be formatted.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `json_normalize` and I think it is performant to use it.

```py
# max_level=0 to avoid expanding InsuranceRates keys to columns.
df = pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=0)[['ProcedureCode', 'ProcedureName', 'Charge', 'InsuranceRates']]
# Convert dict to array of tuples so that we can explode it
df['InsuranceRates'] = df.InsuranceRates.apply(lambda x: [(k, v) for k, v in x.items()])
df = df.explode('InsuranceRates')
df['Insurance Payer Name'], df['Insurance Rate'] = zip(*df.InsuranceRates)

# Rename the rest of columns
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas' automatic ingest is nice, but it doesn't handle everything.  I think this does what you want:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

val = json.load(open('x.json'))
outs = []
for row in val:
    data = {
        'Procedure Code': row['ProcedureCode'],
        'Procedure Name': row['ProcedureName'],
        'Gross Charge': row['Charge']
    }
    for key,val in row['InsuranceRates'].items():
        data['Insurance Payer Name'] = key
        data['Insurance Rate'] = val
        outs.append( data.copy() )

df = pd.DataFrame(outs)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Procedure Code                  Procedure Name  Gross Charge                               Insurance Payer Name  Insurance Rate
0        70023090  HVY MTAL PRO II BLOOD LC706200         27.46                    ACCESS MEDICAL GROUP COMMERCIAL           35.46
1        70023090  HVY MTAL PRO II BLOOD LC706200         27.46                      ACCESS MEDICAL GROUP MEDICARE           23.64
2        70023090  HVY MTAL PRO II BLOOD LC706200         27.46                                   AETNA COMMERCIAL           62.56
3        70023090  HVY MTAL PRO II BLOOD LC706200         27.46                                     AETNA MEDICARE           23.64
4        70023090  HVY MTAL PRO II BLOOD LC706200         27.46                                 AETNA WORKERS COMP           22.93
..            ...                             ...           ...                                                ...             ...
63       20000360         MICU DAILY RM C LEVEL 3       7900.00                                   AETNA COMMERCIAL         6728.00
64       20000360         MICU DAILY RM C LEVEL 3       7900.00                       CENTINELA VALLEY IPA MEDICAL         3950.00
65       20000360         MICU DAILY RM C LEVEL 3       7900.00                          HEALTH NET OF CA MEDI-CAL         1185.00
66       20000360         MICU DAILY RM C LEVEL 3       7900.00  OPTUM HEALTH PLAN OF CALIFORNIA (FKA DAVITA EA...         3400.00
67       20000360         MICU DAILY RM C LEVEL 3       7900.00                PREMIER PHYSICIANS NETWORK MEDI-CAL         3950.00

[68 rows x 5 columns]
```